# Remove Unnecessary Confirmation Popups -- resolved, but why not effective?

Tags: interface

So there's this [ticket](https://developer.blender.org/T37422) from about a year ago and it all seems to have been fixed/improved, meaning there shouldn't be blocking "Delete OK?" popups anymore.
However for me in 2.72b there still are.

Where's the missing link? Or did I miss that this needs to be enabled?

Answer (score 2):

They were removed, but then some were added back later.
Some are still removed, such as copy and paste for objects.

However it seems the confirmation popups for delete and save [have been re-added](https://developer.blender.org/rBb2fdc591c36cf5125eaa528b7f735c3c4393d390) after [a bug report](https://developer.blender.org/T37801), and for good reason IMO. I hit those keys accidentally rather often, and I try to avoid reflexively undoing as much as possible due to various limitations (not to mention speed).

Comment: OK, that's a pity. This behaviour should be user-configurable.