# How do I turn off confirmation dialogues?

Tags: interface, workflow, customization, shortcut

If Blender 2.77a has a user-configurable 'turn delete confirmations' on/off setting, it's sure hidden. To be clear: in *Object Mode*, for instance, when you key <kbd>X</kbd> or press the Delete button on a selected object, a confirmation dialog pops up - confirmations slow my work flow.

Two years ago, an answer to this question ([Remove Unnecessary Confirmation Popups ...](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18608/remove-unnecessary-confirmation-popups-resolved-but-why-not-effective) ) said they were removed - so perhaps this feature is still unavailable?

Comment: What other popup dialogs slow down your workflow? If there is more than one, it is worth (probably) to define a 'custom operator' and wrapping this into an Add-on. [First approach](https://gist.github.com/p2or/55cb588afe6ef8f50ee3b08f9eefdd77) for `Shift X` based on [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43857/3710).

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you can user configure it, but you can speed up the editing by pressing <kbd>X</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>.

<kbd>X</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>X</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> also works, but it's probably slower. You also can change the default shortcut for delete to <kbd>D</kbd> and then press <kbd>D</kbd> twice.

Comment: +1 Good idea !  DUH, why didn't I think of that :))   It would be nice to be able to do X X, instead of X D ... but that works.  Hmmm ... How do we find out what shortcut key is associated with 'D' ?  ( I tried to dump the preferences, but that just generates a python script ... odd. ... and no time to look through them all in the preferences panel ! ) thanks

Comment: Go to user preferences > input and search for the key-binding 'D'